# Existing DocuSign account used for my corporation

Tags: docusignapi

We are experiencing some weird API issues with adding existing users to our company.

I have a private DocuSign account used for testing our DocuSign API integration.  I then use our application to register that email address to our DocuSign company account.  I get my activation email from Docusign.

After going through this process, my existing account password doesnt work.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I'm a little confused, did you create a `developer sandbox` account, a `free trial` account, or is this referencing a `paid production` account that is live?

Comment: We have a developer sandbox account.  We will be going live this month to a paid production account.

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe this very well.   We are trying to add users to our account so that they can sign documents.  When we add a user (email) who is already registered with docusign, the original docusign password is changed and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two DocuSign accounts with the same email address.
However, typically, they would have the same password.
If you are trying to activate a new user for an email address that already has another DocuSign account, that does not require (typically) to set a password, just click the activation email. If you also changed the password, you would have changed it for all accounts associated with that email address.